# How could I ask to someone, but like a suggest, "Vamos a comer algo despues de la clase?"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

It's like an invitation to someone if they want to eat

Comment: This seems to be a straight translation request.  "Let's eat" Or "Do you want to eat?" are fine.  What is your specific problem here?  Google translate can provide good translations to such simple sentences.  What did you already try? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Sure, tried to search in different translators, but there are a lot of answers very different to each other. Look at this, "Shall we eat after class?" I don't if it's correct to use it in this way.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. **Which** translators have you tried? What translations did they offer? What do you think may be the strengths and weaknesses of those proposed translations?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a translation question.

Answer (score 1):

Less formal: “Do you want to get something to eat after class?” (Might be vocalized as “You wanna get something to eat after class?”)

Slightly more formal: Would you like to get something to eat after class?